# I have problem in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

When I log in, all I see is just the background display and nothing else.

I tried to use

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

But still the same.

Comment: I would have re-installed the video card driver myself ;-) since it is more than likely a video card related problem. Please do that too and retry a boot :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot....

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

Go ahead and logout and then log back in and run

```
unity --reset-icons
```